# Returning an empty list with 'or' syntax using Parsley

Tags: python

I'm trying to match a word using Parsley. The grammar that I'm using only works when I make a rule for a generic word. However, I would like to know why it doesn't work the way it is shown from Allen Short's presentation and sample code here (http://bit.ly/1025Qxo) and here (http://bit.ly/17wzUYg).

In his code, he has:

```
rule = (expr1 -> returnval) | -> []
```

But the only way I got it to work was:

```
rule = (expr1 -> returnval) | (expr2) -> []
```

Here's my code:

```python
import parsley

grammar = r"""

myword = "hello"
myrule = (myword:word -> word) | -> []
"""

MyPar = parsley.makeGrammar(grammar,{})
print MyPar("hello").myrule() # works, returns myword
print MyPar("bye").myrule() # doesn't work, throws exception
```

The only way I got it to work was to make a rule for a generic word string using the built-in 'letter' variable.

```python
import parsley

grammar = r"""

myword = "hello"
anyword = <letter+>
myrule = (myword:word -> word) | anyword -> []
"""

MyPar = parsley.makeGrammar(grammar,{})
print MyPar("hello").myrule() # works
print MyPar("bye").myrule() # works, returns empty list
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Paul

Comment: FWIW, what you have looks different than what you say it should be.  (your parenthesis include return val where the original doesn't)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what the rule is supposed to match.

```
myrule = (myword:word -> word) | -> []
```

That will try to match any of the two:

1. `(myword:word -> word)` tries to match `myword` and returns it
2. `-> []` tries to match **nothing**(an empty string, not anything), and returns an empty list

So the behavior you're getting is expected.
If you want to match any word, i think your second code is the way to do it.